# Matrix labels from file

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to load the labels for the `matrix with labels` plot style from a file? I was hoping the following would work:

```
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset key
unset border

$Data <<EOD
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
EOD

$Labels <<EOD
"A" "B" "C"
"D" "E" "F"
"G" "H" "I"
EOD

plot $Data u 1:2:3 matrix with image, $Labels u 1:2:3 matrix with labels
```

but this returns the error message (gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2)

> "matrix.gpl", line 18: warning: matrix contains missing or undefined values

---

My current workaround is a horrible mess where I write the captions into a file as a (one-dimensional) gnuplot array, load that file and then use `u 1:2:(labels[*index depending on $1, $2*])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there are simpler workarounds, but the following seems to work if you plot your label matrix into a table first.

Although, there is the syntax `plot for [col=1:*] ...` which should plot all columns in a loop, but for some reason it doesn't. Maybe because the data is text and not numbers. Hence, you can get the number of columns from `$Data` via `stats`.

**Code:**

```
### labels from matrix
reset session
set size square

unset xtics
unset ytics
unset key
unset border

$Data <<EOD
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
EOD

$Labels <<EOD
"A" "B" "C"
"D" "E" "F"
"G" "H" "I"
EOD

stats $Data nooutput   # get the number of columns from $Data
set table $Labels2
    plot for [col=1:STATS_columns] $Labels u (col-1):0:(strcol(col)) w table
unset table

set style textbox opaque

plot $Data u 1:2:3 matrix with image, \
     $Labels2 u 1:2:3 w labels boxed
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]